# Infinite loop when setting a @Published property

Tags: swiftui, mvvm, infinite-loop

I have a simple view that shows some photos, through a list.  Clicking on any row should display a detailed view of that photo.  I'm using the MVVM pattern.  However, an infinite loop occurs when I try to set the “selectedPhoto” property of the view model.  Is there any way to avoid this loop without having to create a property in the detailed view itself?

Here is the Photo struct:

```
struct Photo: Identifiable {
        var id = UUID()
        var name: String
}
```

Here is the ContentView with an extension (the “updatePhoto” method is causing the infinite loop):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.photos) { selectedPhoto in
                    showDetailView(with: selectedPhoto)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Favorite Photo")
        }
    }
}

extension ContentView {
    func showDetailView(with selectedPhoto: Photo?) -> some View {
        if let selectedPhoto = selectedPhoto {
            viewModel.updatePhoto(selectedPhoto)
        }
        
        return DetailView(viewModel: viewModel)
    }
}
```

Here is the view model:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var photos = [
        Photo(name: "Photo 1"),
        Photo(name: "Photo 2"),
        Photo(name: "Photo 3")
    ]
    
    @Published var selectedPhoto: Photo?
        
    func updatePhoto(_ selectedPhoto: Photo?) {
        self.selectedPhoto = selectedPhoto 
    }
}
```

And here is the DetailView:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    init(viewModel: ViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.selectedPhoto?.name ?? "Unknown photo name")
    }
}
```

Comment: your code logic does not make sense. You are setting `selectedPhoto` at **every**
 iterations of the `ForEach` loop, which then updates the view, which then re-do the settings, etc...
 This is why you have the infinite loop. Explain what your code is meant to achieve,
  what results do you expect.

Comment: You should not do work in the viewbuilder get rid of that custom function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach, using a `NavigationLink` to present the `DetailView`,
and passing the `selectedPhoto` to it using `@State var selectedPhoto: Photo`.

```
struct Photo: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var photos = [Photo(name: "Photo 1"),Photo(name: "Photo 2"),Photo(name: "Photo 3")]
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @State var selectedPhoto: Photo
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(selectedPhoto.name)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.photos) { selectedPhoto in
                    NavigationLink(selectedPhoto.name, destination: DetailView(selectedPhoto: selectedPhoto))
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Favorite Photo")
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `NavigationView` is being deprecated and you will have to use `NavigationStack` instead.